# Running test cases in Rails/Padrino console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, testunit, padrino

Hi I am trying to run test cases from padino/rails console running in test environment. I am unable to get the proper method invocations used by rake task to invoke test-unit library.

Running testcases from  padrino/rails console should reduce the load time of ruby files

Some one please help me pointing out where the load tasks of rake execute before test-unit/rspec is invoked.

Answer (score 1):

Try my version of irb-config. I use this for padrino console

https://github.com/Kshitij-Banerjee/irb-config